# Is .append() time-consuming?

Tags: python, append, readlines

I've been manipulating huge text files these days. Sometimes I need to delete lines.
My way of doing is like below:

```
f=open('txt','r').readlines()
list=[]
for line in f:
    if blablablabla:
       list.append(line)
```

I know for large files, .readlines()is rate-limiting step, but what about .append() step? Does append cost lots of extra time after readlines?
If so, maybe I should find way to directly delete lines I don't want, instead of appending lines I want.

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why read the whole entire file in using `readlines()` if you're going to filter it later?  Just iterate through it saving the lines you want to keep.  You could reduce this down to a couple of lines using list comprehension instead:

```
with open('txt', 'r') as f:
    myList = [ line for line in f if blablablabla ]
```

Comment: Well, using readlines, you're reading the _entire_ file into a list already.  Then you create another filtered list based on its contents.  You don't need the whole file up front using readlines so it's better to not use it at all (or rather change your algorithm to remove undesired lines from that list).  Worrying about the speed of append is unnecessary, it really shouldn't have any effect on the speed of your code.  If you really want to get to the bottom of it, you should profile it and find out yourself.

Comment: Maybe, depends on the size of the file.  List comprehensions are fast.  Also, you won't load the entire file into memory at once, which can maintain performance.

Comment: @wang, even if none of the lines are filtered out, you have at least saved making an extra copy of the whole list.

Comment: thx...but what do you mean by 'depends on size'? My input file is super large, with 50,000,000 lines...So list comprehension will still be much faster for such huge files?

Comment: @wang: Using readlines can be fine as long as the file isn't very big.  50 million lines is definitely very very big so you should avoid it at all costs.  You haven't mentioned what exactly you're doing with these lines but you may want to avoid putting them into a list all together.  If you intend to write them back to a file eventually, it would be better to write them back to a file (as in sunjay's answer) or process them immediately as you loop through the file.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: You should be clear what the big part is. 50 million lines costs 4 bytes per line to make a new copy. The list costs 200 million bytes and the data probably costs a lot more. As an example: `>>> import sys
>>> with open("/usr/share/dict/american-english") as f:
...     lines = [line for line in f]
... 
>>> sys.getsizeof(lines)
412232
>>> len(lines)
98569`

Comment: To be clear, by this: "the data probably costs a lot more", I meant that if you had to copy the data, it would probably cost more than 200 million bytes. But when you copy the list, you don't also copy the data. You just copy pointers to the data.

Answer (score 2):

As a general hint, do this instead, no need to read the complete file first before iterating through it...

```
with open('txt') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        if blablabla:
            my_list.append(line)
```

and don't call a list "list"...

Comment: array isn't such a good choice either (although better than list) as there is also the array module

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list comprehension instead as in Jeff's answer. Depending on how you need to process the data, you may be able to use a generator expression instead.

To answer your question about append()

Python lists are preallocated with some extra space at the end. This means that append is very fast - until you run out of preallocated space. Whenever the list is extended, a new block of memory is allocated and all the references copied over to it. As the list grows, so does the size of the extra preallocated space. This is done so that append is amortized O(1). ie the *average* time for append is fast and constant

Answer (score 1):

In this post, I tried to explain the way lists work and why append is not *very* expensive. I also posted a solution on the bottom which you could use to delete lines.

The structure of Python's lists is like a node network:

```
>>> class ListItem:
        def __init__(self, value, next=None):
            self.value = value
            self.next = next
        def __repr__(self):
            return "Item: %s"%self.value


>>> ListItem("a", ListItem("b", ListItem("c")))
Item: a
>>> mylist = ListItem("a", ListItem("b", ListItem("c")))
>>> mylist.next.next
Item: c
```

Therefore, append is basically just this:

```
ListItem(mynewvalue, oldlistitem)
```

Append doesn't have much overhead, but `insert()` on the other hand requires you to reconstruct the whole list, and will therefore take much more time.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('a=[]\nfor i in range(100): a.append(i)', number=1000)
0.03651859015577941
>>> timeit('a=[]\nfor i in range(100): a.insert(0, i)', number=1000)
0.047090002177625934
>>> timeit('a=[]\nfor i in range(100): a.append(i)', number=10000)
0.18015429656996673
>>> timeit('a=[]\nfor i in range(100): a.insert(0, i)', number=10000)
0.35550057300308424
```

As you can see, insert is much slower. If I were you, I would just **eliminate** the lines you don't need, by writing them back right away.

```
with open("large.txt", "r") as fin:
    with open("large.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in fin:
            if myfancyconditionismet:
                # write the line to the file again
                f.write(line + "\n")
            # otherwise it is gone
```

There is my explanation and solution.

-Sunjay03

Comment: I'm 99% sure your explanation of Python lists is incorrect. They're implemented as a resizable array, not a linked list. The data structure you sketch would have terrible performance for indexing (e.g. `somelist[43]`). Append is fast because there's usually room at the end of the array for another item, and insert is slow because it requires moving all the following elements over one position to make room for the inserted element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to pull it all into memory and then operate on it. Maybe it makes more sense to operate on one line at a time. It's not clear from your explanation which is better.

In any event, here is pretty standard code for whichever approach you take:

```
# Pull one line into memory at a time
with open('txt','r') as f:
    lineiter = (line for line in f if blablablabla)
    for line in lineiter:
        # Do stuff

# Read the whole file into memory then work on it
with open('txt','r') as f:
    lineiter = (line for line in f if blablablabla)
    mylines = [line for line in lineiter]
```

If you go the former route, I recommend that you read up on generators. Dave Beazley has an awesome article on generators called ["Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers"](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/). Highly recommended.